# Create Folder on onedrive using Oauth Authentication

Tags: rest, office365, office365api

I am trying to create a folder or file on OneDrive with using OAuth authorization flow, request and response details are as below,

**Request:**-

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/children?
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer

{
  "name": "Test",
  "folder": { }
}
```

I have got following **error**

**Response**

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "unauthenticated",
    "message": "The caller is not authenticated.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "44a22daf-7c96-4a27-93d7-77df426c9229",
      "date": "2016-10-12T06:32:43"
    }
  }
}
```

**For reference:-**
http://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/item_post_children

I have generated refresh token for authentication process,still facing this authenticationerror issue.Could please help to resolve this problem.

Comment: Hi anyone is there?

Comment: Clearly you are not authorized for this operation. How do you pass the token?

Comment: I have used following references https://graph.microsoft.io/enus/docs/authorization/auth_register_app_v2 &https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/platform/rest

Comment: According to the docs you should add `Authorization: Bearer <your OAUTH token>` header to the request. I don't see that in the request you posted.

Comment: I have already passing Bearer(access token) in request header. I forgot to add that in request header. I have microsoft account with admin previleges still facing that issue.

Comment: Please update your post then. Are you following the authentication procedure described on https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/platform/rest?

Answer (score 0):

I've never used this API, but don't [the docs that you provided](http://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/platform/rest) state that the token should be sent in an Authorization HTTP header and not as a query param?

Like that:

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/children
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer put_your_token_here

{
  "name": "Test",
  "folder": { }
}
```

Comment: Hi anyone is there? Plz could you help me

Comment: You're not providing enough information. If you want someone to help you you need to give more context. See [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide. Obviously you're not authenticated when making the call, so the problem is with how you authenticate. Did you describe it in your post? No.